# Detect press of "cancel" on a Codename One lightweight date picker

Tags: codenameone

On a Codename One lightweight date pickers, the user has four buttons in the top, like in the following screenshot.

I suppose the tapping of the second, third and fourth buttons are detected by the `.addActionListener()` *(please correct me if I'm wrong)*... but I need to detected also the tapping of the "Cancel" button. How can I run some code when the user taps "Cancel"?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't provide a way to detect cancel since we can't consistently detect it on native. As a workaround you can listen to the click on the picker button and unless you get a selection it would mean that the action was canceled.

Alternatively we can add a feature like this for the lightweight picker only. If you need that you can file an RFE on that.

Answer (score 1):

I overcame this by comparing the newly selected picker value to the previously stored value. If it’s the same, I consider it a cancel.